# Ef code first error: EntityType: 'ModelName' has no key defined

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I'm struggling to make a login system in my project but I have a one Exception error.

The error look likes this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0hPI.png]

This is my `Person` model:

```
namespace Entities.Concrete
{
    public class Person:IEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my `User` model:

```
namespace Entities.Concrete
{
    public class User:IEntity
    {
        [ForeignKey("Person")]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastLoginDate { get; set; }

        public int PersonForeignKey { get; set; }
        public Person Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My context look like this:

```
namespace DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework
{
    public class SchoolDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public SchoolDBContext():base("SchoolDB")
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Student> Students{ get; set; }
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Finally, my `Login` method look like this:

```
        public bool Login(string username, string password)
        {

            using (TContext context = new TContext())
            {
                var user = (from p in context.Persons
                            join u in context.Users
                            on p.Id equals u.PersonId
                            where p.IsActive == false &&
                                u.UserName == username &&
                                u.Password == password &&
                                u.IsActive == true
                            select p).FirstOrDefault();
                if (user != null)
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
                
        }
```

I am getting a error in the `user` variable.

I don't know how to assign a key with Entity framework Code first. Can you help me?

Comment: You should add an int Id on the user class.  I think there is an attribute [Key] you can use.

Comment: Can you post IEntity too?

Comment: @Serge Ientity interface is empty

Comment: @Ahmetfurkandur  What do you mean IEntity is empty? Why do you use it then?

Comment: @serge  I using in the repository base desing pattern and ı call IEntity in repository

Comment: ``` public class EfRepositoryBase<TEntity, TContext> : 
        IEntityRepository<TEntity> where 
        TEntity:class,_IEntity_,new()
        where TContext:SchoolDBContext,new()```

Comment: Thank you, but can you look into IEntity interface code. It should be some methods there or maybe some properties.If you use this interface you should implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an 'Id' field for user, so it doesn't know what the Primary Key is for the User type.

Id is used by default by EF or you can specify your own one using the Key attribute.

just add

public int Id { get; set; }

to the User class type

the EF core docs show what to do here too -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations